# Magento sales_order_place_after event not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, sales-order

I have created a custom module to catch the **sales_order_place_after** event, but when i finish a order nothing happen.
My module it's active.

My module looks like this:

**config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <In2itive_OrderComment>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </In2itive_OrderComment>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <ordercomment>
        <class>In2itive_OrderComment_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>in2itiveordercomment_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </ordercomment>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>in2itive_ordercomment/observer</class>
            <method>logShipping</method>
          </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

and **Observer.php** located in *In2itive/OrderComment/Model/Observer.php* :

```
<?php
class In2itive_OrderComment_Model_Observer
{

    public function logShipping($observer)
    {   Mage::log('your debug', null, 'yourlog.log');
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($order->getShippingMethod(), false);
        $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
        $order->save();
    }

}
```

Even a put a print_R i don't receive nothing.
My module it's not catching the event or I don't use the corect log method for this situation?

Comment: Do you need to set it globally the observer event ? Do you need it for both frontend and backend to be executed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this XML code:

```
    <adminhtml>
          <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <mynamespace_mymodule_sales_order_place_after>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observers_Log</class>
                            <method>logShipping</method>
                        </mynamespace_mymodule_sales_order_place_after>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after
          </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

and in the Log observer class:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observers_Log
{
   public function logShipping() 
   {
        // Do logic here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code in file `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <In2itive_OrderComment>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </In2itive_OrderComment>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <ordercomment>
        <class>In2itive_OrderComment_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>ordercomment_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </ordercomment>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>In2itive_OrderComment_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>logShipping</method>
          </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**OR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <In2itive_OrderComment>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </In2itive_OrderComment>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <ordercomment>
        <class>In2itive_OrderComment_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>ordercomment_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </ordercomment>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>ordercomment/observer</class>
            <method>logShipping</method>
          </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<frontend>
      <events>
         <checkout_submit_all_after>
                <observers>
                    <checkout_submit_all_after>
                        <class>in2itive_ordercomment/observer</class>
                        <method>logShipping</method>
                    </checkout_submit_all_after>
                </observers>
         </checkout_submit_all_after>
      </events>
</frontend>
```

Try the above code in your xml

Comment: Can you please add you other answers here and delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible your observer file is not found try keeping your full file path

```
<events>
  <sales_order_place_after>
    <observers>
      <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>In2itive_OrderComment_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>logShipping</method>
      </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```